# Cannot get colored prompt despite setting PS1 in .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, bashrc, prompt

One of the machines I log into via ssh doesn't give me a colored prompt, despite setting it via `.bashrc`. The `.bashrc` part in question is

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
    then # you are root, make the prompt red
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[00;33m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[00;34m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[00;36m\]\w\[\e[00m\]\e[01;31m#\e[00m '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[00;32m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[00;34m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[00;36m\]\w\[\e[00m\]$ '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

and I use it on several other machines with the desired result.

I have no idea why this particular computer doesn't use this `.bashrc`. If I use

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[00;32m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[00;34m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[00;36m\]\w\[\e[00m\]$ '
```

(the line from above), my prompt gets the desired format. `/etc/bash.bashrc` exists, also `/etc/profile`, both look OK to me.

Also, if I ssh into this computer, the xterm title doesn't get set. Normally, it gets set to user@host for this machine. I suspect the same root cause, but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: What's the output of  `echo $TERM` on that computer?

Comment: @Zanna: No, because the force_color_prompt sets color_prompt. Also, this is the standard ubuntu .bashrc and works on all other computers.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch:  xterm-256color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using ssh, you are getting login shell.

From `~/.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists.
```

So make sure this file exists in home directory of the user in which you are trying to login. If it doesn't exists then create the file and force it to read the `~/.bashrc` file by typing this -

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```